# Showing that the limit of a discrete-time system is the same for all initial conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following discrete-time system:

$x(q+1)=Ax(q)+b$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is convergent, $I-A$ is invertible, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can I do the following?

1.) Find the system's equilibrium?

2.) Show that $\lim_{q \rightarrow \infty}x(q)=(I_n-A)^{-1}b$ for all initial conditions $x(0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

For the first part, what I have so far is:

$x=Ax+b$

$-b=Ax-x$

However, I am not sure where to go from here (I am very new to linear algebra).

For the second part, I was told to define a new sequence $y(q)$, $q \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, by $y(q)=x(q)-x^*$ for an appropriate $x^*$. However, I am confused as to how to apply this new sequence.

Comment: What are the conditions on $A$?

Comment: Presumably there are conditions on the eigenvalues of $A$ (like $|\lambda| < 1$)?

Comment: There is a problem in your calculations: $x=Ax+b$ does not lead to $b=x(I-A)$. You can easily that the expression on the right is not possible by checking the dimensions of the different variables.

Comment: @KBS I have written that $b=x(1-A)$, not $b=x(I-A)$, but I see that this is still wrong; thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equilibrium point $x^*\in\mathbb{R}^*$ for the system $x(k+1)=Ax(k)+b$ is defined as

$$x^*=Ax^*+b.$$

Therefore, this equilibrium point solves

$$(I-A)x^*=b.$$

This equilibrium is unique if and only if the matrix $I-A$ is invertible. There is an infinite number of equilibrium points if and only if $I-A$ is singular and $b$ lies in the column space of $I-A$. Otherwise, there is no equilibrium point.

Let us assume here that the equilibrium point is unique or, equivalently, that $I-A$ is invertible. This also means that $A$ has no eigenvalue equal to one. So, we have that $x^*=(I-A)^{-1}b$.

The global convergence of the state to its unique equilibrium point can be established by looking at the stability of the system. Let us define $\tilde x=x-x^*$, then we have that

$$\tilde x(k+1)=A\tilde x(k)$$

and we are left with studying the global asymptotic stability of the origin for this system. The explicit solution is given by $\tilde x(k)=A^kx(0).$ The global convergence to zero for any initial condition is equivalent to saying that $A^k\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. A necessary and sufficient condition for that is that all the eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the open unit disc; i.e. all the eigenvalues have modulus less than 1.

Comment: If you do understand those things you will need to learn elementary algebra and basic discrete dynamical systems. There is no step for your second question, you get that directly from the definition of an equilibrium point. Also $A$ is not necessarily invertible. Read more carefully what I wrote. Finally, if $A^k$ goes to zero as $k$ goes to infinity, then obviously $x(k)$ goes to zero as well irrespective of the initial condition.

Comment: The eigenvalues depend on the values of the entries of the matrix $A$ but you have not given any value for $A$, so we cannot possibly compute its eigenvalues. The matrix $A$ being invertible does not imply that the eigenvalues have a modulus less than 1, pick for instance the matrix $2I$.

Comment: Of course not. Take for instance $A=2I$. We have I-A=-I$. You really need to study linear algebra. You cannot possibly address problems in dynamical systems without knowing quite well linear algebra.

Comment: The modulus is not the absolute value, which is only defined for real numbers. The modulus of a complex number $z=:x+iy$ is given by $|z|=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$. I am sorry to say that but you really need to refresh your math skills. It is not possible to not know that. Also, this information can be easily found with a quick Google search, something you should always do before asking questions here.

Comment: You cannot say that $A$ is convergent. This property is a property of sequence, not of matrices.

Comment: Yeah ok in that textbook, this is how they call it but, in fact, this is the sequence $\{A_k\}_{k\ge0}$ that is convergent.

Comment: I guess the lecture notes you have cover what you need in linear algebra.